# 'FaceDetect.mexw32': The specified module could not be found

Tags: matlab, face-detection

I am using Matlab R2011a on Windows 7 PC, 32 bit. I need to detect a face in an image, and for that I am using the [Viola Jones code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19912-open-cv-viola-jones-face-detection-in-matlab). Irrespective of where I place my required files, I keep getting this error:

> `'FaceDetect.mexw32': The specified module could not be found.`

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you compile the code that you've downloaded with [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)? If so, did you put the compiled MEX file in the required path?

Comment: Eitan the code I downloaded already came with a compiled mex file. And yes I did put the mex file in the required path

Comment: And what path would that be? Isn't there a `??? Invalid MEX-file` part in the error message that you missed out?

Comment: Did you put also the libraries to the matlab path? This error usually means that matlab cannot find a shared library required by the mex file.